# How do I configure guard to only execute tests relevant to what's changed vs re-running the whole test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, guard

After learning about "guard" (I'm using Gem version 2.14.2), and reading this, https://www.chrisblunt.com/ruby-on-rails-running-tests-with-guard-and-docker/, I'm curious if I'm using guard correctly with my rspec tests.  After I launch the guard console using

```
bundle exec guard
```

I'm searching for a way so that my entire suite of rspec tests will not be run when I only edit a single file.  Is it possible to configure guard such that guard will only run tests for a particular spec?  For example, if I edit the file

```
lib/folder1/myclass.rb
```

and spec file

```
spec/lib/folder1/myclass_spec.rb
```

Changes to lib/folder1/myclass.rb will not cause the entire suite of tests to run but rather only the spec/lib/folder1/myclass_spec.rb or at least only specs dependent on the altered class?

Answer (score 0):

Given I have the proper gems in my Gemfile,

```
gem 'guard', '~> 2.16.2'
gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.7.3'
```

And I have a Guardfile in place,

Then lets say I want to run only `spec/policies/user_policy_spec.rb` file whenever `app/policies/user_policy.rb` file changes, then I add the following guard to my Guardfile.

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do
  watch(%r{^app/policies/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/policies/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there anything I can enter in the guard console to enable the same behavior or do I need to edit my Guardfile each time I want to restrict watching to certain files/directories?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, but there is a limited set of commands available via the guard console, this page has a list of those, https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Interacting-with-Guard . If you would want to add additional patterns, AFAIK, then you will have to edit the guard file.